# localtime - executing one after the other- different time_t, but getting same results

Tags: time

When I try to comapre 2 `time_t` values I get unexplained behavour

```
time_t t = 12345;
time_t T = 67890;
struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
struct tm *Tm = localtime(&T);

    char timeStamp[40];
    sprintf(timeStamp, "(1) %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
    Serial.println(timeStamp);
    sprintf(timeStamp, "(2) %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", Tm->tm_year + 1900, Tm->tm_mon + 1, Tm->tm_mday, Tm->tm_hour, Tm->tm_min, Tm->tm_sec);
    Serial.println(timeStamp);
```

I get the exact same date.

When commenting out one of each set, I get the correct answer for each one.

Workaround I did was, but i'm sure there is an elegant way to overcome:

```
        time_t t = 12345;
        time_t T = 12345;
        struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
        uint8_t now_month = tm->tm_mon;
        uint8_t now_day = tm->tm_mday;

        struct tm *Tm = localtime(&T);
        uint8_t save_month = Tm->tm_mon;
        uint8_t save_day = Tm->tm_mday;

        if (now_month == save_month && now_day == save_day)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual page of `localtime()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3p.html) (emphasis mine):

> The `asctime()`, `ctime()`, `gmtime()`, and `localtime()` functions
> shall return values in one of two static objects: a broken-down time
> structure and an array of type `char`. **Execution of any of the
> functions may overwrite the information returned in either of these
> objects by any of the other functions.**

As a solution, I suggest you take a copy of the `struct tm` used by
`localtime()` to store its result, rather than keeping a pointer to it:

```cpp
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
struct tm Tm = *localtime(&T);
```

Comment: Well somehow I missed that line when seeking the answer. I can't see how they managed to pull such bad design (or it  has a reason for that).... I have a shocked look as in your user's pic :) TNX!

Comment: @guyd it is the C language old time API